# How to create a jar file with dependencies

Tags: jar, dependencies

I have made a swing application which uses image files located in a folder named 'res' in current directory. For that I do something like this :

```
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(new String(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\res\\back.png")));
```

It works perfectly fine when I run it from command prompt. But when I make a jar file out of this, it doesn't finds the res folder,although the res folder is inside the jar. However when I copy the res folder in the same directory as the jar, it works again. I want a single jar file without any dependency on external folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load from the classpath maybe:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/back.png");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Comment: It gives the following Exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!      Any Ideas ??

Comment: Never Mind. It worked. Thanks a lot. :)
Just out of curosity, why the method which I was using didn't work ?

Comment: Because the operating system does not know about the files inside the jar. As far as the O/S is concerned, the jar is the file it can see, and it does not see the jar's contents as individual files.